# In the IL code produced, there are some lines missing. What task does the in between lines perform?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConstReadOnly.second p)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  newobj     instance void ConstReadOnly.second::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Here the `IL_0002` is followed by `IL_0007`.
Can any one please give me the actual scenario happening here?

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla but my question is what are these inbetween lines performing and i have'nt got any clue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only labels. There's no code in between. The label represents offset from the beginning off the function in bytes.

```
offset_0:  nop      //size 1 byte
offset_1:  ldc.i4.5 // size 1 byte
offset_2:  newobj instance void ConstReadOnly.second::.ctor(int32) // size 5 bytes
offset_7:  stloc.0 // size 1 byte 
offset_8:  ret
```

You can easily change them and recompile again.

Comment: thanks @powel lukasik._can you suggest me how to track the execution of   the lines of code in visual studio at memory allocation range. we can do debugging but gives no information about memory allocation._

Comment: @murali.j it's a bit unrelated to your original question. I don't think you can do that. There is a plugin to R# that shows hidden allocation - https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-heapview

Comment: lukasik yeah it is unrelated. but thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `ildasm` on your code while specifying the `/BYTES` option, the output is:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
// SIG: 00 01 01 1D 0E
{
  .entrypoint
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2048
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (class ConstReadOnly.second V_0)
  IL_0000:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_0001:  /* 1B   |                  */ ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  /* 73   | (06)000003       */ newobj     instance void ConstReadOnly.second::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0007:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
  IL_0008:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Here you can see the actual bytes used to represent your code on disk as comments. Notice that all instructions use just one byte, except for the `newobj` instruction, which is 5 bytes, which corresponds exactly to the numbers used in the line labels.

Those labels are there so that any jump instructions can show you where they jump. They don't have any relation to lines of code you wrote in C#.